# eclipse equivalence of Tomcat proxyHost/proxyPort values

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

When I was using Netbeans and wanted to look at http traffic using Fiddler, I added the following line to the server startup:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888
```

There doesn't seem to be a place to put this in eclipse; I've read that you can set the proxies from Windows / Preferences / General / Network Connections, and indeed that presents the following page:

[image: Network Connections Preferences]

However, when I do HTTP web service requests and responses (and have verified in the debugger that they're being made and responded to), they still don't show up as traffic in Fiddler. Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: you have also to configure java to deal with the proxy

Comment: Thanks -- how do I do that? Do I have to add the command-line parameters to the eclipse startup?

Comment: yes of course, can you post your code, the part which you declare proxy and the http client?

Comment: What code do you want posted? Sorry, I didn't write the basic HTTP access part, and there are hundreds of classes and dozens of XML files. How do I find the "declare proxy" and "http client" parts you're asking for? I've opened a chat room for us, if you're open to that.

Answer (score 0):

in case of only https traffic is not shown you should add this to lunch:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path\to\keystore\FiddlerKeystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourpassword
```

after exporting the root certificate from fiddler's https options tab.